# finding duplicate and flipping them respectively

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, flip

`df[0] = [0.0000000,0.0082707,0.0132000, 0.0255597, 0.0503554, 0.0751941, 0.1000570, 0.1498328, 0.1996558, 0.2495240, 0.2994312, 0.3993490, 0.4993711, 0.5994664, 0.6996058, 0.7997553, 0.8998927, 0.9499514, 1.0000000, 0.0000000, 0.006114, 0.0062188, 0.0087532, 0.0138088, 0.0264052, 0.0515127, 0.0765762, 0.1016176, 0.1516652, 0.2016828, 0.2516733, 0.3016387, 0.4015163, 0.5013438, 0.6011363, 0.7008976, 0.8006328, 0.9003380, 0.9501740, 1.0000000]`

`df[1] = [0.0000000, 0.0233088, 0.0298517, 0.0425630, 0.0603942, 0.0739301, 0.0850687, 0.1023515, 0.1149395, 0.1230325, 0.1272298, 0.1253360, 0.1130538, 0.0934796, 0.0695104, 0.0445423, 0.0207728, 0.0098870, 0.0000000, 0.0000000, -.0208973, -.0210669, -.0247377, -.0307807, -.0416431, -.0548774, -.0637165, -.0703581, -.0801452, -.0869356, -.0910290, -.0926252, -.0905235, -.0834273, -.0728351, -.0591463, -.0428603, -.0235778, -.0122883, 0.0000000]`

Can you make a python code detect a certain amount of zeros in `df[0]` and lets say for this example if it detects three or more zeros flip the array in the middle? so it looks like `df[0]  = [0.0000000,0.0082707,0.0132000, 0.0255597, 0.0503554, 0.0751941, 0.1000570, 0.1498328, 0.1996558, 0.2495240, 0.2994312, 0.3993490, 0.4993711, 0.5994664, 0.6996058, 0.7997553, 0.8998927, 0.9499514, 1.0000000, 1.0000000, 0.950174, 0.900338,  0.8006328, 0.7008976, 0.6011363, 0.5013438, 0.4015163, 0.3016387, 0.2516733, 0.2016828, 0.1516652, 0.1016176, 0.0765762, 0.0515127, 0.0264052, 0.0138088, 0.0087532 ,0.0062188, 0.006114,  0.0000000]`
and also flip `df[1]` respect to `df[0]`

Comment: Hi I just updated with a example

Comment: Thanks. What are `df[0]` and `df[1]`? Columns?

Comment: Yes, I extracted those data points from a website using pandas

Comment: I've figured it out

Answer (score 0):

```
discont = np.diff(df[0]).argmin()
x1 = df[0][:discont+1]
x1 = np.array(x1)

y1 = df[1][:discont+1]

x2 = df[0][discont+1:]
x2 = np.array(x2)

y2 = df[1][discont+1:]
y2 = np.array(y2)

x_flip = np.flip(x2)
y_flip = np.flip(y2)

x = np.concatenate((x1,x_flip))
y = np.concatenate((y1,y_flip))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).